# how to use MTLSamplerState instead of declaring a sampler in my fragment shader code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, metal, metalkit

I have the shader below where I define a sampler (`constexpr sampler textureSampler (mag_filter::linear,min_filter::linear);`).

```
    using namespace metal;

    struct ProjectedVertex {
      'float4 position [[position]];
      'float2 textureCoord;
    };

    fragment float4 fragmentShader(const ProjectedVertex in [[stage_in]],
                                   const texture2d<float> colorTexture [[texture(0)]],
                                   constant float4 &opacity [[buffer(1)]]){

      constexpr sampler textureSampler (mag_filter::linear,min_filter::linear);
      const float4 colorSample = colorTexture.sample(textureSampler, in.textureCoord);
      return colorSample*opacity[0];

    }
```

Now I would like to avoid to hardly define this sampler inside my shader code. I found `MTLSamplerState` But I don't know how to use it

Comment: What have you tried? What documentation have you read and what specific parts did you not understand?

Comment: Apple documentation tells you how to create a MTLSamplerDescriptor, but as usual with apple docs, doesn't tell you how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a sampler, first create a **MTLSamplerDescriptor** object and configure the descriptor’s properties. Then call the `newSamplerStateWithDescriptor:` method on the **MTLDevice** object that will use this sampler. After you create the sampler, you can release the descriptor or reconfigure its properties to create other samplers.

```
// Create default sampler state
MTLSamplerDescriptor *samplerDesc = [MTLSamplerDescriptor new];
samplerDesc.rAddressMode = MTLSamplerAddressModeRepeat;
samplerDesc.sAddressMode = MTLSamplerAddressModeRepeat;
samplerDesc.tAddressMode = MTLSamplerAddressModeRepeat;
samplerDesc.minFilter = MTLSamplerMinMagFilterLinear;
samplerDesc.magFilter = MTLSamplerMinMagFilterLinear;
samplerDesc.mipFilter = MTLSamplerMipFilterNotMipmapped;
id<MTLSamplerState> ss = [device newSamplerStateWithDescriptor:samplerDesc];
```

**Sets a sampler state for the fragment function:**

```
    id<MTLRenderCommandEncoder> encoder = [commandBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor: passDescriptor];
     ...
    [encoder setFragmentSamplerState: ss atIndex:0];
```

**Accessing from the shader:**

```
fragment float4 albedoMainFragment(ImageColor in [[stage_in]],
                                texture2d<float> diffuseTexture [[texture(0)]],
                                sampler smp [[sampler(0)]]) {

    float4 color = diffuseTexture.sample(smp, in.texCoord);
    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### How to create SamplerState

First, declare `MTLSamplerDescriptor` and configure some properties such as addressModes, magFilter, minFilter.
Second, call `makeSamplerState` method from `MTLDevice`. Most cases default device.
That

You can use the below code. I hope it helps.

```swift
private static func buildSamplerState() -> MTLSamplerState? {
    let descriptor = MTLSamplerDescriptor()
    descriptor.sAddressMode = .repeat // .clampToEdge, .mirrorRepeat, .clampToZero
    descriptor.tAddressMode = .repeat // .clampToEdge, .mirrorRepeat, .clampToZero
    descriptor.magFilter = .linear // .nearest
    descriptor.minFilter = .linear // .nearest
    let samplerState = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()?.makeSamplerState(descriptor: descriptor)
    return samplerState
}
```

#### How to use it

```swift
...

let samplerState = buildSamplerState()
...

// call `makeRenderCommandEncoder` to create commandEncoder from commandBuffer
let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor)
commandEncoder.setFragmentSamplerState(samplerState, index: 0)
```

in your fragment shader

```cpp
fragment float4 exampleShader(VertexIO       inputFragment [[stage_in]],
                              sampler textureSampler [[sampler(0)]],
                              texture2d<float> inputTexture [[texture(0)]])
{
    float2 position = inputFragment.textureCoord;
    // ...
    return inputTexture.sample(textureSampler, position);
}
```

Comment: thanks @won, but in my fragmentshader what I need to do ?

Comment: @loki In your fragment shader, you need to add a new sampler parameter. I edited my  answer.